# How to have a JTextArea appear above Graphics, both within a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, jcomponent

I'm struggling a bit with trying to create a notepad-type thing in Java. So far, I have a class as below, that is really a `JComponent` (`UtilityComponent` extends `JComponent`). In it, you can see that I am rendering graphics to make a notepad shape, and now I want a `JTextArea` within this shape to input stuff. But I can't find a way to make it work; I've tried as it looks now, I've tried adding it in the root `JFrame` (in one case, it took up the whole `JFrame`), I've tried using `JPanel` components and such but can't get it quite right!

```
package jUtility;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Note extends UtilityComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2890336222216437001L;
    private static int width, height;
    private static JScrollPane text;

    public Note(int x, int y, ID id, int w, int h) {
        super(x, y, id);
        width = w;
        height = h;
        JTextArea t = new JTextArea(5,5);
        t.setText("sdfsdaf");
        t.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        t.setLocation(50, 50);
        t.setForeground(Color.RED);
        t.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        text = new JScrollPane(t);
        text.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void tick() {

    }


    public void render(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2.fillRoundRect(x + 2, y + 2, width - 4, height - 4, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.fillRoundRect(x + 23, y + 23, width - 46, height - 46, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRoundRect(x + 25, y + 25, width - 50, height - 50, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: How do you want your version of notepad to look like?

Comment: A gray outline with curved corners, imagine the outline of a vertical ipad maybe, and the middle of it is just a white area where the user can type things into it. I can do the outline with Graphics no worries, it's just getting the JTextArea to co-operate (although it doesn't have to be a JTextArea if there's a better way).

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out after a lot of heartache. I've changed it so my window (Jframe thing) first includes a background JLayeredPane, then I add my graphics first to the JLayeredPane.DAFAULT_LAYER, then my JTextArea to something higher. THe little bit I had trouble with for hours was that I needed to set the location and size of any components addedto the JLayeredPane!

Comment: There are other ways of doing it, but glad you got it sorted.